# Keep accordion menu open while page loads / refreshes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having an accordion menu made with js query that was found online. Initially developed by Ryan Stemkoski. I'm having the accordion menu as a navigation and want it to stay open when a specific link is clicked and its corresponding page is loaded.
The below is the js script

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery("a.mainCategoryCollapsible").click(function() {
     jQuery("ul.panel").slideUp("normal");
      jQuery(this)
      .next()
      .slideDown("normal");
      });
   });
});
```

The below is the html

```
<a class="mainCategory" >Menu1</a>
<ul class="panel ">
    <li>
        <a class="subCategory" href="item1.html " >Item1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="subCategory" href="item2.html " >Item2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="subCategory" href="item3.html " >Item3</a>
    </li>
</ul>
</li>
</br>
<li>
<a class="mainCategory ">Menu2</a>
<ul class="panel ">
    <li>
        <a class="subCategory" href="m2_item1.html " >Item1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="subCategory" href="m2_item2.html " >Item2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="subCategory" href="m2_item3.html " >Item3</a>
    </li>
</ul>
</li>
```

and below is the css

```
.mainCategory {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #111111;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.subCategory {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #505050;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.panel {
  padding-top: 5px;
  margin: none;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  z-index: 500;
}
```

I'm not an expert in JS. I would be thankful for any help and leads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's helpful to give an id to the elements you need to manage, notice for example here I added an id for the menus.

```
<a class="mainCategory" id="menu1">Menu1</a>
  <ul class="panel ">
    <li>
      <a class="subCategory" href="item1.html ">Item1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="subCategory" href="item2.html ">Item2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="subCategory" href="item3.html ">Item3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <br />

    <a class="mainCategory" id="menu2">Menu2</a>
    <ul class="panel ">
      <li>
        <a class="subCategory" href="m2_item1.html ">Item1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="subCategory" href="m2_item2.html ">Item2</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="subCategory" href="m2_item3.html ">Item3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

You can simplify this jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#menu1").next().css('display', 'block'); /* In this line you assign the menu you want to show, accessing the id with the # */

  $(".mainCategory").click(function() {
    $(".panel").slideUp("normal");
    $(this)
      .next()
      .slideDown("normal");
  });
});
```

Working example https://plnkr.co/edit/Ba165CAOEBpw61vIVqsY?p=preview

Comment: That worked like a charm... Thanks a lot. But what if I want it to open dynamically. Like, keep the menu 1 open while any link in menu 1 is clicked and menu2 open when any link in menu 2 is clicked. how do I send the id of the menu item that is clicked to the function?

Comment: Is in this line $("#menu1").next().css('display', 'block'); here you open menu1, so you can change the word meno1 for the id of other menu.

Comment: I understand that but is there a way to do it dynamically rather than hardcoding it? The menus contain links to other pages. So if a page is opened through that link, its specific menu should remain open on page load. How can I pass the id of the menu dynamically to that line?

Answer (score 0):

You have a simple typo in your JS code.

Change `a.mainCategoryCollapsible` selector which doesn't exist in HTML to the existing `a.mainCategory` selector

Comment: ya... its a typo.. sorry I didn't pay attention to it while posting. Its a.mainCategory not a.mainCategoryCollapsible